# Hibernate table update error

Tags: java, hibernate

My web application used hibernate mysql. I can add records to database without having any issue. But if i going to update latest adding record It will not updating. But if I re-start the server(tomcat) and then try to update It's working.

To update the record following condition should be satisfied.

```
//Check record aready exist
public boolean idExists(String id) {
Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();        
List<Officer>  list = (List<Officer>) session.createQuery("from Officer as p where p.idno =" + "\'" + id.trim() + "\'").list();

return (list.size() > 0) ;
}
```

Immediate(return 1) adding records It will returns 0. But one restart the server and update the record It will work. I also verify after adding record it's successfully commit to DB.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static{
try{
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}catch(Throwable ex){
System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
}
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Let me know if something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to [flush](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) the session. Entities are not immediately persisted into the database.

```
session.flush();
```

Comment: I think I had answered the same?

Comment: @commit, yes. same but this one is succinct. +1 from my side.

Comment: really do you think I require that? that does not mattered it is about your image how you gain it here, one should not answered the same like before posted here. what ever welcome here.

Comment: @commit, When I finished my answer then I saw your answer popup. Don't think I saw your answer and I posted. I have respect to other people contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not interact with database immediately after transaction or it does at the time of flushing session, it manages and updates its record to increase system performance in its own way, If you want immediate reflection use :

```
session.flush();
```

After updating records.

Answer (score 0):

I think better you use Transactions here.

You put `session.biginTranasaction();`

Instead do something like,

```
public boolean idExists(String id) {
Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();        
List<Officer>  list = (List<Officer>) session.createQuery("from Officer as p where p.idno =" + "\'" + id.trim() + "\'").list();

tx.commit();
if(session != null){
session.close();
}
    return (list.size() > 0) ;
    }
```

On other end you should generate new session and do other stuffs.